# Dimension dependence in Schauder estimates

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Suppose we have a strongly elliptic PDE with Dirichlet conditions, namely: $L u = f, u_{|\partial D} = 0$ for a strongly elliptic L and a domain $D$.
Suppose also, to make life easy, $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ and $D$ is a ball.

The typical way to estimate the $C^{2,\alpha}$ norm of $u$ is via Schauder estimates---though these are (as far as I know) stated without an
explicit dimension dependence.

Naively, all the proofs I'm familiar with suffer an exponential dependence on $d$.
Is it known whether this dependence is tight (if so, what is the example PDE for this?) or whether one can get better dependence? Any references
(even partial) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that the exponential dependence is already present in the proof of Schauder estimates for the laplacian or it appears in perturbation arguments like freezing coefficients and so on?

Comment: For the laplacian in the whole space the constants do not depend on the dimension. This is proved in "Poisson Stochastic Process and Basic Schauder and Sobolev Estimates in the Theory of Parabolic Equations", N. V. Krylov & E. Priola, Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis, 2017. The usual perturbation arguments should not give too many problems, but one should check.